# Raw Video Data to SRC

Tags: php, video, readfile

I am using the videoJS library to play a video indirectly.

HTML:

```
<video id='example_video_1' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls preload='auto' poster='oilfield.jpg' >

<source src='media.php?name=video.mp4' type='video/mp4' />

</video>
```

media.php PHP:

```
$the_file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/{$_GET['name']}";  
    if( file_exists( $the_file ) )
    { 
      readfile( $the_file ); 
      exit;
    }
```

I did the same thing for image src and it works great but it seems the video doesn't accept the data.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Baseline: If you try to fetch the video manually, does it work? I.e., using `wget`:

```
wget http://WHATEVER.SERVER/media.php?name=video.mp4
```

If that works, what happens if you try to stream that video directly via the video tag, does it work (rather than via redirect)?

If that doesn't work, the file probably isn't set up for streaming. Fast way to confirm if a .MP4 is ready for network streaming:

```
hexdump -C -n 80 video.mp4
```

Do you see 'moov' or 'mdat' in the first 80 characters? If you see 'moov', it's streamable. If you see 'mdat', the file needs to be modified before it is streamed.

To make the file streamable, Google for the tool `qt-faststart` and use it.

Comment: I see moov. When I get it directly it is perfect.

Comment: I think it is the headers?

Comment: working:HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 15:17:24 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=71

Comment: not working:HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 15:17:24 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Cookie
X-Pingback: sitename/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=69
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Are those the return headers when you fetch the raw MP4 file or when you fetch your script?

Comment: the first is the mp4 file(working), the sencond is the script(not working).

Comment: It seems like a video file would be a huge amount of data for readfile() to handle. The official documentation doesn't appear to indicate any such issues, though. However, check the official docs at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php ; a lot of commenters on that page seem to have workarounds for problems encountered when reading large files, including reading smaller chunks and writing them out in turn, or disabling output buffering before calling readfile().